# RegExp on PL/SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

i need help on understanding REGEXP in PL/SQL.

It's simple i just want a validator that validate a Varchar2.
The first letter should be 'a' and the rest of the letter on Varchar2 can be only be 'b' and underscore '_'.

For example this string should be accepted:

```
    aaa , ab , a_ , ab_b , a_b , abbbbbb_ , a___b_ , a_____b_b_b_b_b_b
```

Here is for what i understand should works:

```
    ^[a]([b_]*)*
```

But if i have string like 'abbbbjbbb' it said it's valid string?

What is the right pattern?

Here my anonymous procedure:

```
    set serveroutput on size 1000000 
    DECLARE 
      v_result      VARCHAR2(10); 
      v_bool        BOOLEAN; 
    BEGIN 
      v_bool:=FALSE; 
      IF (REGEXP_LIKE('ab_b_b_bb','^[a]([b_]*)*')) 
        THEN 
          v_result:='VALID'; 
        ELSE 
          v_result:='NOT VALID'; 
      END IF; 
      dbms_output.put_line(v_result); 
    END;
```

Thanks in advance,

berst regards,

Ivan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use end of the line anchor `$`.

```
^[a][b_]*$
```

And also remove the unnecessary group because `[b_]*` alone will do your job..

Comment: Thanks, this is correct answer. Sometime i just need to think simple :)